# How to update Sails Mongo

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have a model field 
say

```
is_active: {
        type: 'integer',
        enum: [0,1],
        defaultsTo: 1
    }
```

and I want to update

```
Rewiew.update({user_id:ObjectId(user_id)}, 
{is_active:0}).exec(function(err,collection){});
```

How can I do so? The data is not getting updated

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use [sails-mongo](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-mongo-db) with [.update()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update).